# <string>をincludeするとコンパイルエラーになる

Tags: spresense

SpresenseのArduino Platformで、`std::string`クラスを使おうと思い、`#include <string>`したところコンパイルエラーが発生しました。

C++標準ライブラリですが、利用不可でしょうか？

**Code:**

```c
#include <string>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

**Error message:**

```
In file included from c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\stl_algobase.h:61:0,

                 from c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\char_traits.h:39,

                 from c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\string:40,

                 from C:\Users\takashi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_278803\sketch_jul17a.ino:1:

c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\cpp_type_traits.h:168:12: error: redefinition of 'struct std::__is_integer<unsigned char>'

     struct __is_integer<unsigned char>

            ^

c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\cpp_type_traits.h:147:12: error: previous definition of 'struct std::__is_integer<unsigned char>'

     struct __is_integer<bool>

            ^
```

（Sony developer forumにも[ポスト](https://forum.developer.sony.com/topic/72/std-string-class)しています）

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [What's the newest way to use C++ stdlibs in Arduino 1.8.2?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/52103), [Embedded Template Library](https://www.etlcpp.com/), [Is the C++ STL fully supported on Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/24790), [maniacbug/StandardCplusplus](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus), [mike-matera/ArduinoSTL](https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL), [Arduinoでテンプレートライブラリを使って、シリアル通信で動くシェルを作る](https://qiita.com/kota65535/items/9349750c9b3a12910347), [andysworkshop/avr-stl](https://github.com/andysworkshop/avr-stl)

Answer (score 1):

コミュニティBotが、この投稿をアクティブにして目についたので、ちょっと試してみました。

提示された次のコードを最新のボードパッケージ（2.3.0）で試してみたら問題なくコンパイルできました。

```
#include <string>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

どこかのタイミングで対応したようですね。

Answer (score 0):

Arduinoの場合、String Objectを使うようです。

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

これは普通に使えましたよ。

Comment: はい、Stringクラスの存在は知っております。

Arduino以外のC/C++でも利用できるライブラリを作成しているため、Stringクラスではなくstd::stringクラスが使えればと思っています。

Comment: なるほど、そうなのですね。
boolの型の問題なのでしょうか。
詳しい方のコメントを待ちます。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージを読んでみました。

> > c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\cpp_type_traits.h:168:12: error: redefinition of 'struct std::__is_integer'
> >          struct __is_integer

[直訳]エラー：'struct std::__is_integer'が再定義されてます。

```
     struct __is_integer<unsigned char>
```

> c:\users\takashi\documents\arduinodata\packages\spresense\tools\gcc-arm-none-eabi\5.4.1\windows\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.4.1\bits\cpp_type_traits.h:147:12: error: previous definition of 'struct std::__is_integer'
>        struct __is_integer

[直訳]エラー：'struct std::__is_integer'の以前の定義は

```
　　struct __is_integer<bool>
```

＝＝
"struct __is_integer < unsigned char>"　と　"struct __is_integer< bool>"　の定義が被っているから駄目だと言っている訳ですが、 素直に読むと"unsigned char"　と "bool"　は別の型ですから被らないですよね。

それが被るということは、"unsigned char" と "bool"は、同じだという宣言がされているのだと思います。
ヘッダファイルの中に

```
#def bool unsigned char
```

か

```
#def unsigned char bool
```

という行がありませんか？　あったら、その行をコメントアウトしてください。
そうすれば、エラーが消えると思います。

Answer (score 0):

根本解決にはならなさそうですが、Fumu 7さんのご回答を参考に
cpp_type_traits.hの中の、__is_integerを削除してみたところ、
正常にstringがinclude出来ました。
__is_integerを使う用事が無いのでしたら、お試しされるのはいかがでしょうか。

ライブラリ作成されているとなると、他の方は使う事が出来なくなってしまいますが・・・

Answer (score 0):

Arduinoはソースの拡張子がinoですが、cppも使えると思います。
拡張子cppの別ファイルに#include を書き、それをinoからコールできないでしょうか？